# how to transfer my localhost database php mysql file to a c panel server without an errors or problems

Tags: php, android, mysql, server, cpanel

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "user";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "databsename";
```

i had finished my app project on a localhost wamp server now i want to activate my app through an server how

$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

Comment: Setup a MySQL user via the cPanel. Then update your php mysql credentials file with the new user credentials. I'm assuming  you can then upload your file via SFTP?

Comment: Have you copied the code to the live server?

Comment: Have you created a database via CPanel?

Comment: Have you restored the database to the live server using phpMyAdmin or other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using PhpMyAdmind, export your databe and upload it in your webhost, if you do not have one, i recommend you hostinger.com

Check this [php_mysql_connect](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) for your php code setup.